# pip not found via zsh yet shows up via python3 -m pip --version

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-catalina

So, I've used homebrew to install python on my MPB (Catalina OS) and currently have both the system python (2.7.16) and python3 (3.9.0).  Using "which" I get the following:

```
$ which python 
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/usr/bin/local/python3
```

When I type "pip list" I get

```
$ pip list
zsh: command not found: pip
```

Yet if I type the following I get this:

```
$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 20.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

What's going on that pip (and pandas) are installed within the python3.9 directory but zsh doesn't find them?  It is an 'alias' issue I need to fix?  I'm concerned to mess with the system python 2.  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a symlink in one of the directories in your PATH variable or manipulate the PATH variable in your shell environment:

Look it up by `echo $PATH` - my result would be:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:...
```

Now I can create a symlink in one of my directories by:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip /usr/local/bin/pip
```

or add `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/` to my PATH by

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/; export PATH
```

Then you would be able to find pip and execute it in zsh.

Comment: It adds....Still that part is missing in your PATH variable: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ Look above to adjust it and add the complete path to pip or create a symlink to pip in one of the folders already in your PATH.

Comment: However to make it permanent, you will have to put it in your profile.

Comment: Got it, I just did and worked, however now I get "permission denied: pip"

Comment: You need admin permissions for the Library folder, so you may want to sudo it or use a user with those permissions.

Comment: Awesome.  Last follow up (I think!):  How do I make it permanent by adding to my profile?

Comment: Ok, found I have Pip3 and that works fine (lists currently installed modules).  Thank you!!!